# iOS UITextField is logging data from another UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

For some reason my emailTextField is logging the string from my passwordTextField. I'm using storyboards, and my outlets are properly connected.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EmQMu9f.png]

This is the code I'm using.

```
NSString *username = [self.usernameTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *password = [self.passwordTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *retypePassword = [self.retypePasswordTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *email = [self.emailTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.emailTextField.text);
    NSLog(@"%@", email);
```

I will always log the string from the password textField.

Comment: And the passwordTextField is properly connected?

Answer (score 0):

Typo in my code set the textfield to the other.... doh.

Thought I was losing my mind.